# Exposing Hibernate metrics via Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, prometheus

I was doing some research on how to expose Hibernate metrics via Prometheus via Spring Boot Actuator, but I was struggling to find out how to do that.

I added the following property to my Spring Boot: Application:`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true`

But all that did was add logging from Hibernate.
I found these two PRs from the Spring Boot project:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/3596
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2157

but it looks like publishing Hibernate metrics via Spring Boot Actuator never made it in because of Micrometer adoption.

Is there a way to expose the metrics that the Hibernate `EntityManagerFactory` collects via Spring Boot Actuator?

Comment: DOes integrating with `Javamelody` helps you..??

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is supported by Spring Boot out of the box.

Besides the property, dependency `org.hibernate:hibernate-micrometer` has to be on classpath. Compare [Spring Actuator documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.hibernate).

Previously you could create a `HibernateQueryMetrics` bean as described in [this micrometer issue](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1006#issuecomment-1058014616).

```java
@Bean
MeterBinder hibernateQueryMetrics(EntityManagerFactory entityManager) {
    return new HibernateQueryMetrics(entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class), "hibernateSession", Tags.empty());
}
```

Support for hibernate metrics has been moved from micrometer to hibernate project.